# Arbitrary values on HCL data

Tags: go

I am trying to get my go code to parse an HCL file that should contain a meta block which would let users define arbitrary keys and values but struggling so far.

```
service {
  name    = "my-service"
  group   = "test"

  meta {
    arbitrary_key1   = "arbitrary_value1"
    arbitrary_key2   = "arbitrary_value2"
  }
}
```

My Go struct:

```golang
type RequestBody struct {
    ServiceSpecs
}

type ServiceSpecs struct {
    Service Service `hcl:"service,block"`
}

type Service struct {
  Name  string      `hcl:"name"`
  Group string      `hcl:"group"`
  Meta map[string]interface{} `hcl:"meta,block"`
}
```

My Go function

```golang
func ServiceHCLtoJSON(HCLFilePath string) (string, error) {
    hclContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(HCLFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Failed to read HCL file: %v", err)
    }

    parser := hclparse.NewParser()
    file, diags := parser.ParseHCL(hclContent, HCLFilePath)
    if diags.HasErrors() {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Failed to parse HCL: %s", diags.Error())
    }

    var serviceSpecs ServiceSpecs
    diags = gohcl.DecodeBody(file.Body, nil, &serviceSpecs)
    if diags.HasErrors() {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Failed to decode HCL: %s", diags.Error())
    }

    jsonOutput, err := json.MarshalIndent(serviceSpecs, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("Failed to marshal to JSON: %v", err)
    }

    return string(jsonOutput), nil
}
```

The current code function works well at populating the values of the hcl files into a json object but it cannot parse the meta block.

I tried adding a block like this:

```golang
    var metaMap map[string]interface{}
    if serviceSpecs.Service.Meta != nil {
        diags = hcl.Decode(&metaMap, serviceSpecs.Service.Meta)
        if diags.HasErrors() {
            return "", fmt.Errorf("Failed to decode Meta: %s", diags.Error())
        }
        fmt.Println("Meta Map:", metaMap)
    }
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: The `meta` block doesn't have any key, what are you expecting to have as a key to decode into a map?

Comment: Also a block value can't have arbitrary attributes. If you want a single map, then you don't want a block at all.